# I want to count the number of agents that pass through 'pedFlowStatistics' line in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

In Anylogic 8.5.1, I am doing a simulation for library evacuation, I have set and agent with Option-list that contains different types of users: students, organizers, graduates, and others. Also, I have set 'custom distribution' parameter to set the distribution values for each user. Until now, I have run the model and every thing is working well.
What I want is:
1. to use 'pedFlowStatistics' line in particular places (I can do this);
2. want to count the users that pass this line (I do not know how to do it);
3. then draw a chart to highlight the different number of users that passes that particular line space (I do not know how to do it).

I need help in the above situation, thanks in advance.

I do not have a Java background.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to count based on conditions with pedFlowStatistics... you can only count the total pedestrians using:

```
pedFlowStatistics.countPeds(); // counts total number of pedestrians
pedFlowStatistics.traffic(); //shows the number of pedestrians per hour
```

You can use these functions directly in your chart.

But since you want to count based on conditions (the type of user they are), you will need to be smart about this and depending on your model, you will have to count pedestrians in a different place... or maybe use 2 ped go to blocks and count in between... it depends on your layout and model.

Comment: Thank you Felipe for your answer. I will try to use your suggestion of using 2 ped go to  blocks